# Filling arrays with random int number

Tags: arrays, matlab, random

I am pretty new to Matlab and am trying to create an m-by-n matrix containing numbers within a specified range (ie. between 0 and 250) with a specified step (ie. [0:10:250]).

Is there an equivalent function, or a workaround, to:

`r = randi ( [a b], m , n )`

where I can specify the step myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

claudiop definitely had a good suggestion, but an alternative to this, in case you have a set of numbers that you want to randomly select from, is to chose random indices of a vector containing your desired numbers

```
nums = 0:10:250;
randIdxs = randi([1,numel(nums)],m,n);
nums(randIdxs);
```

It is randomly selecting numbers from the `nums` vector that will contains the numbers you want to randomly switch between. This solution becomes more useful when there is no clear pattern between all of the numbers, such as `[3,5,7,13,23,37]`. This is no clear spacing or function between primes, so if you wanted to randomly choose prime numbers, this solution would be good.

**Updated**

Edited the code above to use `numel` instead of `length` in case the numbers were in a multidimensional array. Not a huge change at all

Comment: I used to randomly select from a very large matrix but now I need to create an already randomly selected matrix (smaller than the initial one) because the initial matrix is becoming too large to compute.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `randi` function with the numbers between 0 and 25 and then multiplicate the result by 10.

```
r = mystep * randi ( [a b] , m , n )
```

Answer (score 2):

Think about a transformation from a set of random integers over a fixed range ([a b]) to another set with a skip.  Multiplication should take care of the skip... then just be careful of the end condition:

```
r = 10*randi([0 25], m, n);
```

I leave the general formula to you... if you want, you can wrap this in another function randi_skip().